# How do I update a value in table A when creating a row in table B?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, savechanges

My platform has two tables `UserInfo` and `PersonalInfo`. When a user creates a profile the data is saved in `UserInfo`. The view for `UserInfo` has an `@Html.EditorFor`, which is auto populated from Active Directory(if the AD field  is null, a helper class adds N/A in its place). Depending on what application the user decides to use within the platform, more information will be needed so they will need to create a row in `PersonalInfo`. The view for `PersonalInfo` as a `@Html.DropDownListFor` that the user can choose from which will update that users department and cost center.

I would like to update the department for `UserInfo` when the row for `PersonalInfo` is created or updated.

Currently when I create a row it looks like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
var myUserInfo = new myUserInfo
{
    UserId = userNum.Id,
    Address = viewModel.Address,
    City = viewModel.City,
    State = viewModel.State,
    CellPhone = viewModel.CellPhone,
    Department = viewmodel.Department,
    CostCenter = viewmodel.CostCenter,
    ZipCode = viewModel.ZipCode
};
db.MyUserInfos.Add(myUserInfo);
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

How do I update the `Department` field only in the  `PersonalInfo` table before `db.SaveChanges()` is called?

Comment: what about [transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions)?

Comment: I don't mind using `using`. My background is in webforms and I would swear by them when I programmed in webforms. However, I was wondering if there was a more MVC way to go about this. Or perhaps something a bit more elegant.

Comment: The user in that example is attempting to get the `scope` of the ID. This is different than trying to modify a single value on a record, while creating a new record in a different table.

Comment: please add your code for creating `PersonalInfo`

Comment: The only difference between `PersonalInfo` and `UserInfo` is that I call my `CheckIfNullOrEmpty()` 

ie. `ZipCode = viewModel.ZipCode.CheckIfNullOrEmpty();`

Comment: So basically when a `PersonalInfo` is created you want to update the `UserInfo` as well?

Comment: Yes, I took a look at your suggestion. I think I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a row in tableB:-

```
var tableB = new TableB
{
    UserId = userNum.Id,
    Address = viewModel.Address,
    City = viewModel.City,
    State = viewModel.State,
    CellPhone = viewModel.CellPhone,
    Department = viewmodel.Department,
    CostCenter = viewmodel.CostCenter,
    ZipCode = viewModel.ZipCode
};
db.MyTableB.Add(tableB);
```

update a row in tableA:-

```
var tableA = db.MyTableA.Find(tableAId);

tableA.Department = viewModel.Department;

db.MyTableA.Attach(tableA);
db.Entry(tableA).State = EntityState.Modified
```

once you have made all the your required changes, call `db.SaveChanges();`